# How to execute uvicorn balanceAPI:app --reload inside a particular directory?

Tags: python, docker, shell, docker-build, uvicorn

My folder structure is:

-App/

- CMD

  - audit-ledger

    - cryptoexplorer

      - balanceAPI.py
      - start.sh

balanceAPI.py has app=FastAPI()

and start.sh contains the command "uvicorn balanceAPI:app --reload"

This command runs the server when my terminal is in the same directory as that of balanceAPI.py

But I'm trying to build a Dockerfile so on running this start.sh script, it's running it from the root directory (App) and hence is unable to find the balanceAPI.py file and is throwing error.

How to I make the command execute inside the cryptoexplorer directory?

currently my start.sh file contains only:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
uvicorn balanceAPI:app --reload
```

But I have also tried with:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cd cmd/audit-ledger/cryptoexplorer/
uvicorn balanceAPI:app --reload
```

and

```bash
#!/bin/sh
uvicorn cmd.audit-ledger.cryptoexplorer.balanceAPI:app --reload
```

Neither worked.

Can anyone help me out with what I should put inside the start.sh script to make it work?

Comment: What is the actual error message?  Do you need to set the Dockerfile `WORKDIR` so it's in the right directory?  How are you running the container; do you have some sort of volume mount that's hiding the main module?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have set "WORKDIR /app" in my Dockerfile. This is because after running the start.sh script, I'm executing some other scripts that are in the root (/app).